# Bookmarks, Places nautilus sidebar position Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, bookmarks, places

12.04 shows my bookmarks at the top of the side panel. After upgrading to 14.04 it shows Places, Devices, Bookmarks, Network.
Is there any way to move Bookmarks top of the side panel or set position for these items?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way you can do that in the standard file manager for Ubuntu, but there is a way in Nemo: a fork of the built-in file manager (a big brother some might say) but available in a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/nemo).

Have a look at their [official web-site](http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com/?p=198) first.

PPA's contain unsupported software so you should always be careful and make a personal judgement before installing any PPA's even when given in an answer on Ask Ubuntu. That being said, I've been running Nemo for over 6 months now and would not go back *ever*.  :-)

To install this PPA, go to a terminal and type the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/nemo
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nemo
```

and put your bookmarks wherever you want them, have advanced list options, built-in terminal, sticky zoom options, ...